# "We've detected you're using an older version of Chrome."

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

When visit google, there’s an error/status that appears in the Chrome if it’s out of date.  I feel it's displayed by the website itself. But I haven't found any documents about when this message will come up. 
[image]

Comment: It seems to me that this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might have a look at [su], but be sure to read their guidelines for posting questions beforehand. see . [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons might be just there's an updated version of chrome available. As per the suggestion [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/vWdltwPNDUU), go to [chrome://chrome](http://chrome://chrome) and you will see chrome starting to update automatically. You should see something like the below.

[image: the settings page that updates chrome]

Comment: I am getting this error on my own Browser built on Android Webview - Its my Web Browser and not Google Chrome. How do i avoid this popping up?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but this question is not about programming, so off-topic for Stack Overflow. It might be fit for [su] instead for instance.

Comment: Note that, if the question and answers have positive votes, they may not be cleaned up automatically after they are closed. That's why some experienceed user systematically downvote questions and answers when off-topic. You get the reputation back whe nthe whole quesiton with answer gets deleted for good.